# sprintf and php

Tags: sql, printf

The following function gives all the related data except artist_id, when run I have checked all elements in the database and ok.

If I change the artist_id to an actual 'id' it shows in the result of the function as WHERE artist_id = 4 AND........

Confess I do not understand what is causing this.

Result of the function:

```
SELECT `image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`,     `albumname`, `ext`, `timestamp`
FROM album_images WHERE artist_id = AND member_id = 1 AND        
image_album_id = 160

<?php
function get_data_nxtprv($fields, $where) {
$return = FALSE;

// Template
$template = "SELECT %s "
    . "FROM album_images "
. "WHERE artist_id = " . $artist_id. " 
       AND member_id = ".$_SESSION['member_id']." %s";

// Current record 
$sql    = sprintf($template, $fields, $where);
$query  = mysql_query($sql);
$query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

//print_r($sql);
// If data has been found
if ($query_result)
{
    $return = $query_result;
}

return $return;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am  not entirely sure I understand your question.  But I noticed that your function uses three input variables:

```
$artist_id, $fields, $where
```

But $artist_id is not getting passed as an argument.

You would need to modify the function call:

```
function get_data_nxtprv($artist_id, $fields, $where)
```

Comment: Hi, Isn't the artist_id act the same as the member_id and comes under the where variable?

Comment: Hi, Anyway I tried what you said to no avail. Do I have the correct syntax for the $template section?

Comment: Hi, The function is used by another and you get this $results['current'] = get_data_nexprv($fields, "AND image_album_id = {image_album_id}" ); This is repeated substituting either previous or next for current.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Given an album_id and member_id are you trying to retrieve the corresponding artist_id, album_name and timestamp? It is not clear whether you want the artist_id and member_id to be in the WHERE clause or in the SELECT clause.

Comment: [SOLVED] I was not getting the artist_id. Many thanks for all comments

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your SQL

```
SELECT `image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`, `albumname`, `ext`, `timestamp`
FROM album_images WHERE artist_id = AND member_id = 1 AND        
image_album_id = 160
```

should it not be

```
SELECT `image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`, `albumname`, `ext`, `timestamp`
FROM album_images WHERE member_id = 1 AND        
image_album_id = 160
```

if `artist_id` is one of the fields you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, Yes there is an error because the artist_id does not give a data response from the query. I do not understand why. Code in  query "WHERE artist_id = ".$artist_id." AND member_id = ". $_SESSION['member_id']."  Member_id is returned correctly.

Comment: ah ok, so can you show us the code where you call the function that returns the code you listed above - it sound like the problem lies there.